# Unexpected token error in older Electron using Typescript and Vite

Tags: typescript, vue.js, electron, chromium, vite

I am running a barbones Vue/Vite typescript enabled project and connecting to it from an Electron instance started by Blink.jl.  Now I don't think Blink.jl is that important here, I don't think it's the issue.  The issue I believe is an older version of chrome running on it which as you can see is v69.  This required adding polyfills.

Now I am seeing this unexpected token error in my transpiled typescript file:

[image: View of the error]

And here is the view of the transpiled file:

[image: View of the transpiled file]

Comment: yes this is a new syntax and v69 doesn't support it you have to install compiler targeting

Comment: Native class fields arrived in es2022 which isn't a contemporary of v69 based on just release dates. Syntax cannot be polyfilled. You need to configure TS to not use es2022 or later as a target